# An extended simple, funny, easy linked stack of lists in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

This post is the continuation of [A simple, funny, easy linked stack of lists in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283128/a-simple-funny-easy-linked-stack-of-lists-in-java).

What's new:

1. Now I have varargs for pushing/linking multiple values per call.
2. Provided the unit tests.

**`com.github.coderodde.util.Multistack.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements a stack of lists.
 * 
 * @param <T> the type of the data items stored in the multistack.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 8, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Feb 8, 2023)
 */
public final class Multistack<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {
    
    private static final class MultistackIterator<T> 
            implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private final Multistack<T> stack;
        private final long expectedModCount;
        private MultistackNode<T> previouslyIteratedNode;
        private MultistackNode<T> nextNodeToIterate; // null by default.

        MultistackIterator(Multistack<T> stack) {
            this.stack = stack;
            this.expectedModCount = stack.modCount;
            this.nextNodeToIterate = stack.top;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            checkModCount();
            return nextNodeToIterate != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            checkModCount();
            
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Iteration exceeded.");
            }
            
            List<T> list = nextNodeToIterate.extract();
            previouslyIteratedNode = nextNodeToIterate;
            nextNodeToIterate = nextNodeToIterate.next;
            return list;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if (previouslyIteratedNode == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No item to remove.");
            }
            
            unlink(previouslyIteratedNode);
            previouslyIteratedNode = null;
            stack.size--;
        }
        
        private void unlink(MultistackNode<T> node) {
            if (stack.top == node) {
                stack.top = node.next;
            }
            
            if (node.prev != null) {
                node.prev.next = node.next;
                node.prev = null;
            }
            
            if (node.next != null) {
                node.next.prev = node.prev;
                node.next = null;
            }
        }
        
        private void checkModCount() {
            if (expectedModCount != stack.modCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException(
                        "Multistack changed while iterating.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new MultistackIterator<>(this);
    }

    private static final class Node<T> {
        private final T datum;
        private Node<T> next;
        
        Node(T datum) {
            this.datum = datum;
        }
    }
    
    private static final class MultistackNode<T> {
        
        private final Node<T> head;
        private Node<T> tail;
        private MultistackNode<T> next;
        private MultistackNode<T> prev;
        private int size;

        public MultistackNode(T datum, MultistackNode<T> top) {
            Node<T> node = new Node<>(datum);
            head = node;
            tail = node;
            size = 1;
            next = top;
        }
        
        void append(Node<T> node) {
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            size++;
        }
        
        List<T> extract() {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(size);
            
            for (Node<T> node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {
                list.add(node.datum);
            }
            
            return list;
        }
    }
    
    private int size;
    private long modCount;
    private MultistackNode<T> top;
    
    public void push(T... additionalData) {
        checkArrayNotEmpty(additionalData);
        
        for (T datum : additionalData) {
            MultistackNode<T> node = new MultistackNode(datum, top);
            node.next = top;
            
            if (top != null) {
                top.prev = node;
            }
            
            top = node;
        }
        
        size += additionalData.length;
        modCount++;
    }
    
    public void push(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        for (T datum : iterable) {
            MultistackNode<T> node = new MultistackNode<>(datum, top);
            node.next = top;
            
            if (top != null) {
                top.prev = node;
            }
            
            top = node;
            size++;
        }
        
        modCount++;
    }
    
    public void pushSibling(T... additionalData) {
        checkArrayNotEmpty(additionalData);
        
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "Trying to link a datum to an empty Multistack. " + 
                    "Please push an element before doing this operation.");
        }
        
        for (T d: additionalData) {
            top.append(new Node<>(d));
        }
        
        modCount++;
    }
    
    public void pushSibling(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        for (T datum : iterable) {
            top.append(new Node<>(datum));
        }
    }
    
    public List<T> peek() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "Peeking from an empty Multistack.");
        }
        
        return top.extract();
    }
    
    public List<T> pop() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "Popping from an empty Multistack.");
        }
        
        List<T> returnValue = top.extract();
        top = top.next;
        size--;
        modCount++;
        return returnValue;
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
        modCount++;
        top = null;
    }
    
    private void checkArrayNotEmpty(T[] array) {
        if (array.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Empty arrays as arguments are not allowed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.MultistackTest.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MultistackTest {

    private final Multistack<Integer> stack = new Multistack<>();
    
    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        stack.clear();
    }
    
    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void emptyIterator() {
        stack.iterator().next();
    }
    
    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void throwsOnDoubleRemove1() {
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        
        Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        iterator.remove();
    }
    
    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void throwsOnDoubleRemove2() {
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        
        Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        iterator.remove();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void iteratorRemove1() {
        stack.push(1, 2);
        Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(2, stack.size());
        iterator.remove();
        assertEquals(1, stack.size());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2), stack.pop());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void iteratorRemove2() {
        stack.push(1, 2, 3 ,4, 5);
        stack.pushSibling(5);
        
        Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        iterator.next(); // Point to 5.
        iterator.next(); // Point to 4.
        iterator.remove(); // Remove 4.
        iterator.next(); // Point to 3.
        iterator.next(); // Point to 2.
        iterator.remove(); // Remove 2.
        iterator.next(); // Point to 1.
        
        iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(5, 5), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(3), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1), iterator.next());
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.MultistackDemo.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public final class MultistackDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multistack<Integer> stack = new Multistack<>();
        System.out.println("Created a stack:");
        
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.pushSibling(3, 4);
        stack.push(5);
        stack.pushSibling(6);
        stack.push(7);
        
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        
        set.add(10);
        set.add(11);
        set.add(9);
        
        stack.pushSibling(set); // We can add sibling via an Iterable.
        
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(20, 21));
        
        stack.push(list); // We can push another Iterable.
        
        for (List<Integer> level : stack) {
            System.out.println(level);
        }
        
        Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = stack.iterator();
        
        iterator.next();    // Now we are at [21].
        iterator.remove();  // Remove [21]
        iterator.next();    // Now we are at [20].
        iterator.next();    // Now we are at [7, 9, 10, 11].
        iterator.remove();  // Remove [7, 9, 10, 11].
        
        System.out.println("After removal iteration:");
        
        for (List<Integer> level : stack) {
            System.out.println(level);
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo output**

```
Created a stack:
[21]
[20]
[7, 9, 10, 11]
[5, 6]
[2, 3, 4]
[1]
After removal iteration:
[20]
[5, 6]
[2, 3, 4]
[1]
```

**Critique request**

Is there anything to improve? Please tell me!

Comment: Multistack is a bit non-descriptive name. Should it just be "StackOfLists" instead? I have never seen this data structure before and a bit of searching for multistack showed some quite different structures. Do you have a use case for this? I have a hard time figuring out why a regular Stack<List<T>> wouldn't be both sufficient, easier to understand and more flexible. You probably should document the logical difference between operations adding to the top of the stack but to the end of the list.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Kiitos palautteesta. Suomi perkele! :-D